# foreach loop counter not working

Tags: c#, windows-8

I'm having problems handling my `foreach` loop. I'm not sure why but when I debug it, my pellets count equals to zero. It is supposed to be 103. When I run the program, it doesn't show any result. Is there something that I missed out in my codes?

Code:

```
List<Pellets> pellets = new List<Pellets>();
bool gotPellet = false;
foreach (var pellet in pellets)
{
    if (pellet.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        var rectPellet = pellet.GetRect(cnvMain);
        var pelletCellPoint = pellet.GetCellPoint();

        rectPacman.Intersect(rectPellet);
        gotPellet = true;

        pellet.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        AddPellet(pellet);
        mazeValues[(int)pelletCellPoint.X, (int)pelletCellPoint.Y] = ' ';
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm using windows 8 metro app c#

Comment: Don't you have a debugger?

Comment: just a quick glance, `break` will jump out of `foreach`

Comment: You remove all the pellets in the.first line

Comment: @Sayse no he just doesn't add some pellets

Comment: @WiiMaxx, he expects there to be 103 so therefore OP must have added some to begin with

Comment: @Sayse but then the first line should looks like `pellets = new List<Pellets>();` there is an difference

Answer (score 7):

The `pellets` list can not have 103 elements in it since you're creating a new list at the top of the code, and adding nothing to it.

Comment: Despite the tortured English, this is indeed correct. Let's see if we can improve that :-)

Comment: How is the "pellets" length 103? You are initialising the List before the loop, how is that mate?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Pellets> pellets = new List<Pellets>();
```

Your list is empty so your foreach loop does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Pellets> pellets = new List<Pellets>();
```

At this point you have created a new list which is empty. You do not add any members and so this list is still empty when you attempt to enumerate it.